# IF statement not working in Android

Tags: android, if-statement

i am using if statement to restrict user to must enter a phone number in editText but after pressing the button the activity starts event of the editText is empty

```
     et= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);   
    if (et != null){
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MediaPlayer mp1=        MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.button_test);
            mp1.start();

            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Register.class));  
            }   
    });      }
```

Comment: if(et.getText().toString().equals(null))

Comment: i have added this , now its not opening the activity even if i put a number in editText

Comment: @Adil Waqer: Accept one of the answers. Click on the big white hook top/left of the regarding answer and earn at least 2 reputation points ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

et will not be null, et will have the address if the editText. 
use

```
if(!et.getText().toString().equals(""))
```

Answer (score 1):

your if condition is wrong. try this:

```
if (!et.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
 et= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
 Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); 
 b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    if(et.getText().toString().length!=0){
    MediaPlayer mp1= MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.button_test);
        mp1.start();

        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Register.class));
        }

     }   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`et` is the instance of the control. Please use `if` in following code

```
et= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);   

b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (et.getText() != null && et.getText().toString().length > 0){
            MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.button_test);
            mp1.start();
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Register.class));  
        }
    }   
});
```